# Custom Control : Using a custom control to show on the properties explorer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, properties, custom-controls

I'm currently writing a custom control but am struggling to be able to view a custom class on the properties explorer in visual studio. Can anyone suggest what i may be doing wrong.

[View from VS 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpMsR.png)

```
    public class GelButton : Button
    {
        private Appearance _ButtonAppearance = new Appearance();

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("Appearance.")]
        public Appearance ButtonAppearance 
        {
            get { return this._ButtonAppearance; }
            set 
            {
                this._ButtonAppearance = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

public class Appearance
        {
            private Color _Top = Color.FromArgb(255, 44, 85, 177);
            private Color _Bottom = Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 198, 241);
            private Color _Colour3 = Color.White;
            LinearGradientMode _GradientMode = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;

            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The Color to use for the top portion of the gradient fill of the component.")]
            public Color Top { get { return _Top; } set { _Top = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The Color to use for the Bottom portion of the gradient fill of the component.")]
            public Color Bottom { get { return _Bottom; } set { _Bottom = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("Gradient fill colour 3 of the component.")]
            public Color Colour3 { get { return _Colour3; } set { _Colour3 = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The gradient fill mode of the component.")]
            public LinearGradientMode GradientMode { get { return _GradientMode; } set { _GradientMode = value; } }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem I found the following solution

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ButAppearance))]    
public class GelButton : Button
    {
        private Appearance _ButtonAppearance = new Appearance();

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("Appearance.")]
        public Appearance ButtonAppearance 
        {
            get { return this._ButtonAppearance; }
            set 
            {
                this._ButtonAppearance = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

public class Appearance
        {
            private Color _Top = Color.FromArgb(255, 44, 85, 177);
            private Color _Bottom = Color.FromArgb(255, 153, 198, 241);
            private Color _Colour3 = Color.White;
            LinearGradientMode _GradientMode = LinearGradientMode.Vertical;

            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The Color to use for the top portion of the gradient fill of the component.")]
            public Color Top { get { return _Top; } set { _Top = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The Color to use for the Bottom portion of the gradient fill of the component.")]
            public Color Bottom { get { return _Bottom; } set { _Bottom = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("Gradient fill colour 3 of the component.")]
            public Color Colour3 { get { return _Colour3; } set { _Colour3 = value; } }
            [Category("Appearance"), Description("The gradient fill mode of the component.")]
            public LinearGradientMode GradientMode { get { return _GradientMode; } set { _GradientMode = value; } }

        }

internal class ButAppearance : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
}
```